# How to use Bitrise.io and Firebase on public repository

Tags: ios, github, continuous-integration, bitrise

I have a public Github project which uses Firebase, so it needs a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. Since this file includes a bunch of API keys and such, I added the file to `.gitignore`

Today I set up Bitrise.io for CI purposes. Adding the project went just fine but now every time I trigger a build (or push to `master`), the build fails since the `GoogleService-Info.plist` is obviously missing from the repo.

Is there any kind of workaround to still hide the `.plist`file from Github but expose it to Bitrise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **Secrets** or **Generic File Storage** (https://devcenter.bitrise.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-generic-file-storage/) in the Workflow editor.

There's just one limitation, that as your app is a public one on bitrise.io those secrets won't be available in Pull Request builds. But based on what you wrote that shouldn't be a problem, you don't want to expose it for anyone who can send a PR.

Note: if you'd store it as a **Secret**, then you can just write it into a file via a simple `Script` step: `echo "$MY_PLIST_SECRET" > ./path/to/file.plist`